# How do I reference the OpportunityCompetitor object in a VF?

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, related-list

I am trying to create a table of the list of competitors on the opportunity. this list will be shown as part of a VF email template.
Like the opportunity team, opportunity partners and so on, I assume I can also present the opportunity competitors.
I am trying to write this:

```
<apex:repeat var="competitor" value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityCompetitor}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!competitor.Name}

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!competitor.id}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
```

but the system just shouts:

> Error: Invalid field OpportunityCompetitor for SObject Opportunity

I looked in the documentation for the API name of competitors and only found "OpportunityCompetitor"

I would be thankful if you could help me solve this.

Udi

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you are just missing an 's'. It should be OpportunityCompetitors assuming relatedTo is the opportunity.

**Controller**

```
Opportunity relatedTo = [Select Name, Id, (Select Id, CompetitorName,Strengths,Weaknesses From OpportunityCompetitors) From Opportunity where id =: someOpptyid];
```

**VF Page**

```
<table>
    <apex:repeat var="competitor" value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityCompetitors}">
    <tr>
    <td>{!competitor.CompetitorName}</td>
    <td>{!competitor.Strengths}</td>
    <td>{!competitor.Weaknesses}</td>
    </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

**Option 2**

If you are using the Opportunity standard controller, then you can simply do this

```
 <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >

        <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityCompetitors"> 

        </apex:relatedList>

 </apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks AslamK! 
this actually solved one problem and got me closer to the finish line but unfortunately I am not there yet :)
Now it does not let me reference ANY of this object's fields! 
So annoying! Do you have a clue?

Comment: What do you mean that id does not let you reference any of the object? Are you querying that related object and its field in your controller?